How to manual copy mp4 file?
I have tried using some popular editors like: sublime text, notepad++ to open mp4 file and after copy content of it. After copy, I added the mp4 extension to the newly copied file. As a result, the new mp4 file cannot be opened even though it has the same content as the old file, so what did I miss when copying it, a header for example?

Bad idea. Editors are text editor. MP4 are binary files. Opening and saving binary file in a text editor very often ends up in changes to the content because of charset de-/encoding. Why don't you simply copy the file? If you want to manually edit a file use a hex editor.

maybe the new file does not have the mp4 extension

The problem is that I have an external ssd drive, but when I copy data from there, I check its content as an old file, but when I open it, it is damaged, it is similar to the above case when I need to copy the content with the editor.

Then may be the files have been downloaded e.g. via FTP in text mode (instead of binary mode).

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to copy mp4 or any binary non-printable content as if it was a text file then the closest option is to open the file using a hex editor (ex. HxD for Windows), instead of a text editor like Notepad++.
This will not help if the file is damaged in any way.
